# Exiting a while loop that is outputting to a CSV file with user input and not including the last input

Tags: python, csv, while-loop

I am trying to use exit a while loop by checking to see if user input is equal to a specific word.

```
def add():

    with open("pyquiztest1.csv", 'a+') as f:
        new_question = input('Enter your question. Type exit to exit: \n')
        while new_question != 'exit':
            new_question = input('Enter your question. Type exit to exit: \n')
            f.writelines(f'{new_question}\n')
            if new_question == 'exit':
                break
```

This code works but I can't figure out how not include the string `exit` to the CSV file.

csv output:

```
q,d,g
t,h,i
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break from the loop before you write to the file.

- ask for input
- check condition
- either write to file or break from the loop

```py
EXIT_COMMAND = "exit"
with open("pyquiztest1.csv", 'a+') as f:
    while True:
        new_question = input(f'Enter your question. Type {EXIT_COMMAND} to exit: \n')
        if new_question == EXIT_COMMAND:
            break
        f.writelines(f'{new_question}\n')
```

Side notes:

- use a "constant" / variable for the same value, otherwise you can change one occurrence of "exit" and forget about the others

Comment: It would be clearer and more idiomatic with `while True`, as the condition on the while loop will never be used to exit it.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille fair point, changed that

Answer (score 1):

You just need a while loop as follows:

```
def add():
    with open("pyquiztest1.csv", 'a+') as f:
        while (question := input('Enter your question. Type exit to exit: ')) != 'exit':
            print(question, file=f)
```

**Note:**

Requires Python 3.8+

Answer (score 0):

To not repeat the same user `input` (on code level) use the following approach (check the input value before writing into the file):

```
with open("pyquiztest1.csv", 'a+') as f:
    while True:
        val = input('Enter your question. Type exit to exit: \n')
        if val == 'exit':
            break
        f.write(f'{val}\n')
```

Comment: Why is *writelines()* preferred over *write()* ? The effect is the same in this case - just wondering

Comment: @DarkKnight, it's not preference, it was taken from the OP's code. The main question is not about that

Answer (score 0):

You can save a lot of duplication here using the python3.8 [assignment expression](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html). In your code you have the while that is checking the condition and then you check it again in the loop body. This is not good for error checking and maintainance.

```
def add():

    with open("pyquiztest1.csv", 'a+') as f:
        
        while(new_question := input('Enter your question. Type exit to exit: \n') ) != "exit" :
            f.writelines(f'{new_question}\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the csv library:

```
import csv

EXIT_COMMAND = "exit"

with open("pyquiztest1.csv", 'a+', newline='') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    while True:
        new_question = input(f'Enter your question. Type {EXIT_COMMAND} to exit: \n')
        if new_question == EXIT_COMMAND:
            break
        csv_writer.writerow([new_question])
```